# AsyncTask Thread with Intent

Tags: android, multithreading

I run loading screen which should show current status "scanning packages, etc" . So that my activity wouldn't freeze I must use thread, but then I can't update status (TextField). I tried using *AsyncTask* but that didn't helped me at all, still after running I see text field unchanged.

```
public class LoadingScreen extends Activity  {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.loadingscreen_layout);
            try {
                startLoadingScreen();
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("Scanner","Scanner",e);
            }

        }

        public void startLoadingScreen(){
            try{
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        new ScanningOperation().execute("Scanning");
                        //loadingScreen.setStatus("Scanning");
                        final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
                        //get a list of installed apps.
                        List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                        //changeIntent();
                        //finish();

                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("Thread","Thread");
            }

        }

        private class ScanningOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                return params[0];
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                TextView txt = findViewById(R.id.statusView);
                txt.setText(result); 

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {}

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
        }
    }
```

Comment: what do you want to do in background ?? exactly ?? get the list of packages ??

Comment: yes get list of packages is one of thing I want to do, and I want to keep status on loading screen for each step, like if device is collecting packages on loading screen I could see in text field "scanning packages" and that goes for other steps.

Comment: you mean you  would  **just** show scanning packages ?? and the list would be fetched in background thats it ryt ?? when would you do that , in some button click ??

Comment: First of all there is no need to start an `AsyncTask` from another `Thread` except main. And you can use [publishProgress()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress(Progress...)) to update progress from `doInBackground()`

Comment: just for scanning packages ..you dont need to have a progress bar(with progress updates) ..it will hardly take a few microsecs..

Comment: actually with all code it takes a while when i need process all packages. It takes up to few mins. And for progress Im using just spinning circle with TextField bellow it indicating what current state it is